# how to change bar chart color in canvas js?

Tags: html, canvasjs

I want to make different color for two bar charts, my code is:

```
    <div class="chartAreaWrapper">
    <canvas baseChart id="monthChartDistance" height="700" width="1200" color="Blue"
            [datasets]="barChartDataDaysDistance"
            [labels]="barChartLabelsDays"
            [options]="barChartOptions"
            [legend]="barChartLegendDays"
            [chartType]="barChartTypeDays"
            (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
            (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
    </div>
    <canvas id="monthChartAxisDistance" height="700" width="0" color="Blue"></canvas>

    <div class="chartAreaWrapper">
    <canvas baseChart id="monthChartDuration" height="700" width="1200"
            [datasets]="barChartDataDaysDuration"
            [labels]="barChartLabelsDays"
            [options]="barChartOptions"
            [legend]="barChartLegendDays"
            [chartType]="barChartTypeDays"
            (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
            (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
    </div>
    <canvas id="monthChartAxisDuration" height="700" width="0"></canvas>
```

But the color of first chart doesn't change to blue, both chart are still the same color.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an instance of canva.js chart there has to be an objects of options:
something like that:

```
ngOnInit() {
  let chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
    theme: "light1", // "light2", "dark1", "dark2"
    title: {
      text: "Basic Column Chart - Angular 8"
    },
    data: [
      {
        color: "blue",
        type: "column", // Change type to "bar", "area", "spline", "pie",etc.
        dataPoints: [
          { label: "apple", y: 10 },
          { label: "orange", y: 15 },
          { label: "banana", y: 25 },
          { label: "mango", y: 30 },
          { label: "grape", y: 28 }
        ]
      }
    ]
    });
    chart.render();
  }
}
```

and inside of the object there are data array which contains some properties. And one of the property can be color property, by which, you can set a color of your chart
[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/canvasjs-angular-column-chart-xdbzeq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)